# Angularjs error when calling factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, factory

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to call a function in a factory but I am getting the below error,

```
Error: [$injector:undef] Provider 'todoStorage' must return a value from $get factory method.
```

This is my factory,

```
todomvc.factory('todoStorage', function ($q,$http) {
var STORAGE_ID = 'todos-angularjs-perf';

 function get(){
            var promise = $q.defer();

            $http.get('http://localhost/test.php').success(function(data){
                    promise.resolve(data);
            });

            return promise.promise;
        }

});
```

And this is how I call the function,

```
var todos = $scope.todos = todoStorage.get();
```

What exactly is happening and why this error coming up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
todomvc.factory('todoStorage', function ($q,$http) {
var STORAGE_ID = 'todos-angularjs-perf';


 function get(){

   return $http.get('http://localhost/test.php');
 }

 return{get:get};

});

//call the service like this
todoStorage.get().then(function(res){
  $scope.todos = res.data;
});
```

Your code is not returning the actual service factory. Since you are using factory you have return some JavaScript object pointing to your internal function. Otherwise it's not a valid factory, and your external code will have no way of getting to the internal get function.

Comment: The error is resolved, but why I am not getting the data. The promise is returning null. Does defer make the call synchronous?

Comment: I recommend that you resolve the promise on the calling side instead of inside the service. Also, based on the implementation of $q, promises will never behave synchronously, even if the promise is resolved immediately.

Comment: I would not create a new promise here. It's easier to just return the original promise generated by $http.

Comment: I tried to access the data after calling the service as u mentioned. But only the promise object is getting printed.